# How do I hide automatically generated child columns in web2py's SmartGrid?

Tags: web2py

I love the way web2py smartgrid creates automatic child links to referenced tables. But i can't find how to customise them.

I want to show only some of the child table links ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1gs3.png)). I know i can eliminate referenced tables by specifying the `linked_tables` option. And I can use the option to make new custom `links`. And I can use `fields` to hide columns for the main table.

But how do I hide one or more of the automatically generated child columns for the tables that *are* included in `linked_tables`?

And is it possible to change the link text?

Comment: I never got this working well. So I wrote an integration to datatables.net. It gives easy control over columns and links and ordering and more. More info here [link](https://groups.google.com/g/web2py/c/TOogoD99lPc). A link is there to some videos and github repo if someone else wants to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, in the method that creates your smartgrid you can make any linked column hidden by putting something like

```
db.TableOfTheColumnToHide.columnToHide.readable = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion KEHT. I am not sure how to implement this on a generated column that comes from the SmartGrid. They dont have names and I dont think the columnToHide option will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

i went through hell of a time to get this solution

grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.child, linked_tables=['parent'],links=dict(child=links),searchable= dict(child=True, parent=False),create=dict(child=True, parent=False),deletable=dict(child=True, parent=False),editable=dict(child=True, parent=False),details=dict(child=True, parent=False))

same you can modify for custome links tooo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bkamath. I dont really know how this works I'm sorry. I did test it out. See the screenshot here [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/qtvshwiZi) .  I wan't to hide one or two of the links shown in yellow. The auth_users table links to a StudentClasses table. I just want to show the main link not the 'created_by' and 'modified_by' ones. Can i do that with your code?

Comment: i had same issue i had solved by 
defining headers={'parent':{'parent.parentName':'parent'}} in  `grid= ` statement in controller.


field names are case sensitive and in healder and filed define only fields which you need to display in grid view

You can check out web2py method here: [link] http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators/#Methods

Comment: also if you do not need user_signature, you can make it off.. by user_signature=False, in grid statement. That will be quick fix, but i always find user_signature are very handy for audit purpose.